# Temptable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Query #1:

```
SELECT a.*  
INTO #TempTable1 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Vendor,
         CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(50), DateModified, 101)='01/01/1900' THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(50), DateModified, 101) END AS 'Date of Last Check', 
         CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(50), PaycommissionDate, 101)='01/01/1900' THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(50), PaycommissionDate, 101) END AS 'Date of check for month',
         SUM([Original $ Total]) 'Amount'
     FROM
         Tbl_Commission_Reconcilation  
     WHERE
         Vendor IS NOT NULL
         AND MONTH([Order Date]) = MONTH (GETDATE())
     GROUP BY
         Tbl_Commission_Reconcilation.Vendor,
         CONVERT(varchar(50), DateModified, 101),
         [Sales Rep], PaycommissionDate) a
```

Output:

```
Vendor              Date of Last Check   Date of check for month       Amount
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Boston Warehouse    12/12/2017            12/12/2017                   919.00
Woodlink            12/12/2017            12/12/2017                   979.86
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT b.*  
INTO #TempTable2  
FROM
    (SELECT 
         [Sales Rep],
         SUM([Commission $ paid]) 'Commission $ paid'
     FROM 
         Tbl_Commission_Reconcilation  
     WHERE 
         Vendor IS NOT NULL
         AND MONTH([Order Date]) = MONTH (GETDATE())
     GROUP BY 
         [Sales Rep]) b
```

Output 2:

```
Sales Rep       Commission $ paid
---------------------------------
Tammy Hanson    379.77
```

Final query:

```
select * 
from #TempTable1, #TempTable2
```

Final output:

```
Vendor      DateofLastCheck Dateofcheckformonth Amount  Sales Rep      Commpaid
Boston 
Warehouse   12/12/2017     12/12/2017          919.00   Tammy Hanson    379.77
Woodlink    12/12/2017     12/12/2017          979.86   Tammy Hanson    379.77
```

Output 2 shows only one commission paid 379.77 for Tammy Hanson.But in final output shows 2 times commission paid 379.77.How to rectify this problem?
How to show only one commission paid in the final output?Please, any one helps me.

Comment: How are these two outputs related?  I'm not seeing a relation here.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add row_number to your queries

For Table1

```
SELECT a.*  
INTO #TempTable1 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Vendor,
         CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(50), DateModified, 101)='01/01/1900' THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(50), DateModified, 101) END AS 'Date of Last Check', 
         CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(50), PaycommissionDate, 101)='01/01/1900' THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(50), PaycommissionDate, 101) END AS 'Date of check for month',
         SUM([Original $ Total]) 'Amount',
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Vendor, DateModified, [Sales Rep]) RN
     FROM
         Tbl_Commission_Reconcilation  
     WHERE
         Vendor IS NOT NULL
         AND MONTH([Order Date]) = MONTH (GETDATE())
     GROUP BY
         Tbl_Commission_Reconcilation.Vendor,
         CONVERT(varchar(50), DateModified, 101),
         [Sales Rep], PaycommissionDate) a
```

For Table 2

```
SELECT b.*  INTO #TempTable2  
    from
    (SELECT [Sales Rep],SUM([Commission $ paid]) 'Commission $ paid',
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Sales Rep]) RN
    from Tbl_Commission_Reconcilation  where Vendor is not null and Month([Order Date])= MONTH (Getdate())
    group by [Sales Rep])b
```

and also left join table1 and table2 with this RN column

```
select 
  *
from #TempTable1 t1
    LEFT JOIN #TempTable2 t2
ON t1.RN = t2.RN
```

Comment: Vendor Date of Last Check Date of check for month Amount Vendor Sales Rep Commission $ paid
Boston Warehouse 12/12/2017 12/12/2017 919.00 Boston Warehouse Tammy Hanson 183.80
Woodlink 12/12/2017 12/12/2017 979.86 Woodlink Tammy Hanson 195.97

Comment: It shows 2 times TammyHanson.But i want show only one Tammy Hanson and sumof commission paid.Is it possible?

Comment: still, I am getting same result.Vendor Date of Last Check Date of check for month Amount Sales Rep Commission $ paid
Boston Warehouse 12/12/2017 12/12/2017 919.00 Tammy Hanson 183.80
Woodlink 12/12/2017 12/12/2017 979.86 Tammy Hanson 195.97

Comment: Super, Very nice.Thank you so much.Now it's working.Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the duplicate values because you are using a Cross Join ( Cartesian Product) here. Please specify at least 1 condition to match the records from both tables so that the values will be displayed only against the desired records.

As per your current query, it will return all the possible combinations of rows in both tables. change it like this

```
select * from #TempTable1 T1,#TempTable2  T2 WHERE T1.ColumnName = T2.ColumnName
```

or you can also say

```
select * from #TempTable1 T1
inner join #TempTable2  T2 
WHERE T1.ColumnName = T2.ColumnName
```

-- if you want records that have matches on both tables

or

```
select * from #TempTable1 T1
    left join #TempTable2  T2 
    WHERE T1.ColumnName = T2.ColumnName
```

-- if you want records from #TempTable1 and display null for TempTable2 if no matching records

Answer (score 2):

It appears you can just do one query. The larger query already has [sales rep] in the group by clause, so why not just sum the commission?

```
SELECT
      a.* INTO #TempTable1
FROM (
      SELECT
            Vendor
          , CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(50), DateModified, 101) = '01/01/1900' THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(50), DateModified, 101) END
            AS 'Date of Last Check'
          , CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(50), PaycommissionDate, 101) = '01/01/1900' THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(50), PaycommissionDate, 101) END
            AS 'Date of check for month'
          , SUM([Original $ Total]) 'Amount'
          , [Sales Rep]
          , SUM([Commission $ paid]) 'Commission $ paid'
      FROM Tbl_Commission_Reconcilation
      WHERE Vendor IS NOT NULL
      AND MONTH([Order Date]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
      GROUP BY
            Tbl_Commission_Reconcilation.Vendor
          , CONVERT(varchar(50), DateModified, 101)
          , [Sales Rep]
          , PaycommissionDate
) a
```

Comment: as per your query i got below mentioned output:       Boston Warehouse 12/12/2017 12/12/2017 919.00 Tammy Hanson 183.80
Woodlink 12/12/2017 12/12/2017 979.86 Tammy Hanson 195.97   
It shows 2 times TammyHanson.But i want show only one Tammy Hanson and sumof commission pait.Is it possible?

Comment: but the commission relates to "that row" even if the sales rep is repeated